# Django JSONFIeld (.objects.create) data is not getting inserted

Tags: django, postgresql

I am new to django / postgres. I have created a [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField) model, by following along with the documentation. In this instance I am attempting to store a json file in psql.

```
class TestResults(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    data = JSONField()
```

This model is then used in a celery task.

```
# task for running tests by marker 
def run_tests_mark(test_marker):
    os.chdir('/lib/tests')
    # only allow specific strings to be passed in by the user
    if test_marker not in ['smoke', 'regression']: 
        return 'You have entered an invalid term. Please use either smoke of regression.'
    # run pytest command with self contained reporting
    results = pytest.main(['-p', 'no:django', '-v', '--json-report', '-m', test_marker])
    # convert report to json
    report_json = json_report('.report.json')
    # insert the json report: 
    TestResults.objects.create(name='test_run_id_00', data=report_json)
    return None
```

I am using a helper to grab the resulting report

```
def json_report(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)

    return data
```

I can also see that the report itself is generated and in the expected directory.

A table named `test_automation_app_testresults` has been created when I connect to psql however when I run `select * from test_automation_app_testresults` nothing comes back.

My questions are:

- Am I using JSONField correctly?
- Should there be some kind of 'commit()' following the create?
- With the table getting created is that a confirmation that things are working?

Comment: The documentation does not say anything about it, but if you create the object and then you do `test_results.data = report_json` and `test_results.save()` should work

Comment: Thank you for the response. I ended up using: `test_results_report = TestResults.objects.create(name='test_run_id_00', data=report_json)`
`test_results_report.save()`

Comment: You are welcome! Nice that is working!